# cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.xpackage.x2006.digitalSignature.CTRelationshipReference?

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

While trying to verify a signed docx file using apache POI OOXML using this code snippet.

```
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(inputStream);
        SignatureConfig sic = new SignatureConfig();
        sic.setOpcPackage(pkg);
        SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
        si.setSignatureConfig(sic);
        boolean isValid = si.verifySignature();
```

Here's my exception stacktrace: telling me that there are a class cast exception !!

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.xpackage.x2006.digitalSignature.CTRelationshipReference
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.services.RelationshipTransformService.init(RelationshipTransformService.java:150)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMTransform.<init>(DOMTransform.java:92)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.<init>(DOMReference.java:205)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMManifest.<init>(DOMManifest.java:102)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLObject.<init>(DOMXMLObject.java:112)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.<init>(DOMXMLSignature.java:163)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshal(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:206)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo$SignaturePart.validate(SignatureInfo.java:237)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo.verifySignature(SignatureInfo.java:296)
    at com.hamed.docx_signer.DocxSigner.verify(DocxSigner.java:74)
```

Here's my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx-signer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>docx-signer</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here's my log:

```
2014/11/19 01:17:28 DEBUG org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection  - Parsing relationship: /_xmlsignatures/_rels/origin.sigs.rels
2014/11/19 01:17:28 DEBUG org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection  - Parsing relationship: /word/_rels/document.xml.rels
2014/11/19 01:17:28 DEBUG org.apache.xml.security.Init  - Registering default algorithms
2014/11/19 01:17:29 DEBUG org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection  - Parsing relationship: /_rels/.rels
2014/11/19 01:17:29 DEBUG org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo  - Digital Signature Origin partName: /_xmlsignatures/origin.sigs - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.digital-signature-origin
2014/11/19 01:17:29 DEBUG org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo  - XML Signature partName: /_xmlsignatures/sig1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.digital-signature-xmlsignature+xml
2014/11/19 01:17:29 DEBUG org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.services.RelationshipTransformService  - constructor
2014/11/19 01:17:29 DEBUG org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.services.RelationshipTransformService  - init(parent,context)
2014/11/19 01:17:29 DEBUG org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.services.RelationshipTransformService  - parent java type: javax.xml.crypto.dom.DOMStructure
2014/11/19 01:17:29 ERROR org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo  - error in marshalling and validating the signature
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.xpackage.x2006.digitalSignature.CTRelationshipReference
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.services.RelationshipTransformService.init(RelationshipTransformService.java:150)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMTransform.<init>(DOMTransform.java:92)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.<init>(DOMReference.java:205)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMManifest.<init>(DOMManifest.java:102)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLObject.<init>(DOMXMLObject.java:112)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.<init>(DOMXMLSignature.java:163)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshal(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:206)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo$SignaturePart.validate(SignatureInfo.java:237)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo.verifySignature(SignatureInfo.java:296)
    at com.hamed.docx_signer.DocxSigner.verify(DocxSigner.java:74)
    at com.hamed.docx_signer.DocxSignerTest.testVerify(DocxSignerTest.java:72)
```

Would you please help?!

Comment: If you depend on `ooxml-schemas-1.1` and `ooxml-security-1.0` instead of `poi-ooxml-schemas`, does that fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a release problem of 3.11-Beta3 :(

For the time being, please add the ooxml-security.jar to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>ooxml-security</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Until it's staged to central, you'll need to add the apache repo:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-repo</id>
        <name>Apache Repo</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Update**: will be fixed by [1640846](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1640846) i.e. the next poi release

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the verification of the signed file failed


2014/11/22 02:41:37 DEBUG org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference  - Expected digest: 1vWU/YTF/7t6ZjnE44gAFTbZvvA=
2014/11/22 02:41:37 DEBUG org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference  - Actual digest: cWVWRxsODBK3kLvh++Lh732GYgc=
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature  - Manifest ref[/_rels/.rels?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml] is valid: false

Comment: To debug xml signature issues, you might want to save the digest inputs to a file. See first comment of https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56836